# Cannot connect to Postgres database with XAMPP, Laravel, PDO

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

I've seen a couple of posts related to this, but nothing has worked so far.

My current setup is XAMPP, Laravel 5, and Postgres. Here is my `welcome.blade.php` file:

```
@extends('layout')

@section('content')
<?php

    $results = DB::select('select * from logs', array(1));
    echo $results;
   //  $host        = "host=127.0.0.1";
   //  $port        = "port=5432";
   //  $dbname      = "dbname=test";
   //
   // $db = pg_connect( "$host $port $dbname user=postgres password=root"  );
   // if(!$db){
   //    echo "Error : Unable to open database\n";
   // } else {
   //    echo "Opened database successfully\n";
   // }
?>
@stop
```

When I visit `http://localhost:8000/`, I get the error: `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.`

I also uncommented the pgsql extensions in the php.ini file. I thought that maybe postgres is disabled, so I uncommented the part and commented out the PDO part. Whenever I visited `http://localhost/resources/views/welcome.blade.php` I got

`@extends('layout') @section('content') Opened database successfully @stop`

This is good. I know the postgres is working.

Here is my `.env` file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=test
DB_USERNAME=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

and in my `database.php` file, I have this:

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'pgsql'),
```

and

```
'pgsql' => [
'driver' => 'pgsql',
// 'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
// 'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
// 'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'test'),
// 'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'postgres'),
// 'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'root'),
'host' => 'localhost',
'port' => '5432',
'database' => 'test',
'username' => 'postgres',
'password' => 'root',
'charset' => 'utf8',
'prefix' => '',
'schema' => 'data',
'sslmode' => 'prefer',
],
```

I wasn't sure if I needed `env()` in that or not. I've tried both ways, neither work.

Am I missing something here? Help would be appreciated.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your configuration and everything to do with your database. It's not running, or not listening on port 5432, or there's a firewall blocking you.

Comment: @aynbar `It's not running` as in the database? I just disabled all of my firewalls and made sure the database is up and running. On netstat, it says `postgres.exe` is on port 5432. Any suggestions?